# How to adjust certain things in the Longtable

Tags: tables, fonts, tabularray, math-fonts

Hi there i am going to post a MWE code, which probably has a few packages that arent needed for the MWE version but are used in my main file. I need to adjust 3 things in the generated table. The script which i am using has a a certain font for the numbers. This doesnt really bother me except for in Tables... and i cant find a way to fix it. Do you have any suggestions? Should i maybe use the same font for number as for the letters? Then i wouldnt need to put $$ around every number. But i dont wnat to change the font which is used in the Equation environment

1. In the caption the word "Table" has to be in bold
2. In the caption the number "1" after the world "Table" should be in an $$ environment.
3. Is there a way to make all values of the Table be in the $$ environment? My only solution right now is to put manually a $$ around every value.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage {caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}




\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath} 

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{Cochineal}[
  Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},
  Style=Swash 
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlf}{\lfstyle}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tlfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Tabular,Lining}}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttlf}{\tlfstyle}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
  \tlfstyle
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
  \tlfstyle
}



\setsansfont[
    Path            = fonts/,
    BoldFont        = Roboto-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont      = Roboto-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont  = Roboto-BoldItalic.otf,
    Scale = 0.83 
]{Roboto-Regular.otf}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\begin{document}



\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Gitterschnittergebnisse der raumtemperaturgehärteten Proben PUA 2403 X, Y, Z, AA, AB und AC bei},
    label = {tblr:GT RT},
    ]
{width=\linewidth,colspec={X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]}}
\hline
 \textbf{PUA Nr.} & \textbf{Substrat} & \textbf{Blech Nr.} & \textbf{GT Nr. 1} & \textbf{GT Nr. 2} & \textbf{GT Nr. 3} & \textbf{Mittelwert} & \textbf{Stabw. S}\\
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2403 X}& Oxsilan & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
&Fe Phosphatiert & 1 &1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Zn Phosphatiert & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: i deleted those lines, those werent needed for the example

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem Nr. 3 "Is there a way to make all values of the Table be in the $$ environment? My only solution right now is to put manually a $$ around every value."

Solution:
I added the command

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlf}{\lfstyle}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tlfstyle}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Tabular,Lining}}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttlf}{\tlfstyle}

\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}{%
  \tlfstyle
}
```